# How to do multiple where statements for the same column in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause, multiple-instances

Using rails 3, How could one do multiple where statements without complicated stuff or extra gems?

Im having this column "accepted" and would like to get all the values where accepted == false and accepted == null

Both of examples below fail:

```
    @scholars = Scholars.where(:scholar_id => current_user.id).where(["accepted = ? or accepted = ?", true, null])
```

and

```
    @scholars = Scholars.where(:scholar_id => current_user.id).where(:accpeted => true).where(:accepted=> null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer should be

```
@profiles = Profile.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :accepted => [true, nil]).order(:accepted)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
@scholars = Scholars.where(:scholar => current_user, :accepted => true).all + 
            Scholar.where(:scholar => current_user, :accepted => nil).all
```

Did you name your model "Scholars"? Models are traditionally singular... if you named it properly, this should be `Scholar.where(...)`.

Comment: Tried this one also, forgot to add to my post... it only gets where accepted => true.. the nill param is neglected.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It is hard to perform an OR query in Rails while staying away from writing raw SQL. I've updated my answer to combine two queries. It isn't ideal, but it will give the desired result.